# How to prevent profile pages from revealing when I was last online on steam?

Tags: steam

I always start my steam with "Automatically sign into Friends when I start Steam" disabled.

It seems to work — people can't see if I'm online. But when I check the profiles of my steam buddies, there I can find myself and the time when I was "Online last time".

There the last time is always set to the time when I logged into my account. I don't like it — how to disable this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to hide your Steam status from others?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94211/is-there-any-way-to-hide-your-steam-status-from-others)

Comment: @MBraedley This question says they are already doing what that question's answer is; so, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your Profile Private so that they can't access to your Profile. If you do so, they won't be able to see when you were online, but on the downside, they can't see anything.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. The problem could be now, that people still can see my "last online timestamp" when they take a look in their own friendlist.

Answer (score 3):

To get around this, I created another Steam account, and added it as a "family" account so I could share the game library of my regular account.

When I want to be anonymous, I log into the new account. If I want to be available for my friends etc, I log into the original account.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to change.

Answer (score -1):

If you press firends, and then on the arrow next to yourself you can press offline. Then you will appear to be offline for all players. But if you want to make sure no one can find out anything, press Steam in the left upper corner and then go offline!

Comment: When his steam starts up it automatically does that, he states that in his question