# Appear online while gaming on steam

Tags: steam

Is there any way to appear just online and not in-game to your friends (not offline, I know how to do that) while you're in a game?

Comment: [This is the answer you're probably looking for](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/340338/18916)

Comment: @senpai I suspect you correct.  You should make it an answer and claim your well-deserved upvotes ;)

Comment: @Steve-O That, uh, isn't how duplicates work.

Comment: @Corsaka It wasn't closed yet when I made the comment